# HIVE Combining two query results when one query is an Inner Join with less rows

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table (table 1) that I need to get user counts from and to create a percentage from it.  The background is that the table has details of users on this table.  I need to get a percentage of all the users that have had a specific usage which is only obtained by an inner joined to another table (table 2).

```
Table1AccountNumber     Table1WithJoinAccountNumber
1                       1 
2                       3
3                       4
4
```

The end results for calculations with a tool such as Tableau would be to be able to do the following with a list of account numbers, which are dependent on a date of usage and other parameters as well.

```
COUNT(DISTINCT Table1WithJoinAccountNumber)/ Count(distinct Table1AccountNumber)
with source above = 3/4 = 75%
```

My struggle is that I want to link the two results so I can get an accurate count of each account number as the inner join will have less accounts in the results.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the aggregation before joining:

```
select t2.cnt * 1.0 / t1.cnt
from (select count(distinct accountid) as cnt from Table1AccountNumber) t1 cross join
     (select count(distinct accountid) as cnt from Table1WithJoinAccountNumber) t2;
```

Presumably, the accounts in the second table are known, so a `join` is not needed.

Comment: How would this work if we need a percentage of users per a certain day?

Comment: @epv . . . New questions should be asked as *new* questions, not in comments.  This question is clearly not about a ratio for every day.

Answer (score 0):

You need left join:

```
select  day, count(t2.accountid)/count(t1.accountid) as pct    
from (select distinct accountid, day from Table1AccountNumber) t1
     left join  
     (select distinct accountid, day from Table1WithJoinAccountNumber) t2
     on t1.accountid = t2.accountid and t1.day=t2.day
group by day
```